# trouble building ROS package lwr_robot

Tags: ros, gazebo, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building lwr_robot I get the following error:

[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/build' [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lwr_controller.dir/src/lwr_controller.o /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/src/lwr_controller.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::LWRController::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’: /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/src/lwr_controller.cpp:100:49: error: ‘class gazebo::math::Angle’ has no member named ‘Radian’ /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/src/lwr_controller.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::LWRController::UpdateChild()’: /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/src/lwr_controller.cpp:169:116: error: ‘class gazebo::math::Angle’ has no member named ‘Radian’ make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/lwr_controller.dir/src/lwr_controller.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/alexander/fuerte_workspace/lwr_robot/lwr_simulation/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lwr_controller.dir/all] Error 2

There seems to be an issue with the gazebo package.
Do you have any experience with this?

Regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61379/trouble-building-ros-package-lwr_robot/) by [xelda1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/4742/xelda1988/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look at this new (experimental!) package:

https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr

it still requires some tuning of the PID gains, but the arm can already be moved a bit with MoveIt!

---

Originally posted by [marcoesposito1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/7591/marcoesposito1988/) with karma: 191 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0